# Libgdx set PerspectiveCamera rotation to initial

Tags: android, camera, rotation, libgdx

I can not find how to set the rotation to the initial one.

I have a view that you can look around a model. At the side, there is a button that allows to reset the position of the camera to the inital one. Right now, I set the position and lookat to the original one. The camera go back to the right place, but it's not the case for the rotation.

So my question is how to set back the rotation to the right one (I guess 0);

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "lookat" to reset. The `lookAt` method changes the `direction` vector to point at the coordinate you specify, relative to the camera's current `position`.

To set the camera upright and pointing at -Z like it does by default, do this:

```
camera.direction.set(0, 0, -1);
camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
camera.update();
```